# Render specific meridians/parallels of a sphere

Tags: rendering

I would like to render specific meridians or parallels of an UV Sphere to obtain [this kind of plain images](http://archive.hokulea.com/images/navigation_and_weather/celestial_sphere.jpg).

I have been trying with the Wireframe Modifier but I can't find an easy way to render just the ones I want.

Any clues to do it in an easy way?

Thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with an UVSphere.

[image]

Select the edge loops you want (Equator, Parallels, Meridians)

Press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate the selected edges.

[image]

Select the newly created object and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to Convert the object to Curves:

[image]

Give the curve some bevel or extrusion:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much cegaton for your reply! It's perfect ;)